# Assigning new role to already existing user in RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws, amazon-rds-aurora, database-user

"We have an RDS instance hosted for Aurora PostgreSQL, specifically using the 'db.r5.xlarge' instance type. When we initially set up the RDS instance, a default user named '**rdsadmin**' was automatically created with the '**SUPERUSER**' role.

During the setup, we also created a master user named 'X'. However, 'X' does not have 'SUPERUSER' permissions.

Our goal is to assign the '**pg_read_server_files**' role to the user 'X'. The challenge we face is that we don't have the login credentials for the 'rdsadmin' user since it was a default root user provided by AWS during the RDS instance creation.

We attempted to use the command "GRANT pg_read_server_files to X;", but we encountered an error message: "ERROR: Cannot issue GRANT on the 'pg_read_server_files' role. Detail: Cannot GRANT on the 'pg_read_server_files' role without being a member of the role."

Are there any possible workarounds to assign a new role to an existing user given this situation?"

Comment: Forget it. Do you think Amazon will let you access files on the database server file system?